# Config propagation to child modules

Tags: nestjs

I'm looking for a way to:

- propagate config of a dynamic module into child modules
- change `imports` of a dynamic module depending on config

Assume we have a dynamic module `A` that can optionally use dynamic sub-modules `A1` and `A2`.

With static configuration, it's pretty obvious how to implement what's asked in the question:

```js
@Module({})
export class AModule {
    static forRoot(options: AModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
        const imports = [];
        if (options.includeA1)
           imports.push(A1Module.forRoot(options.a1Options));  
        if (options.includeA2)
           imports.push(A2Module.forRoot(options.a2Options));   
        return {
          module: AModule,
          imports: imports,
          providers: [],
    };
  }
}
```

Now imagine config comes from a ConfigModule. NestJS docs and many satellite modules show how to inject config service into a provider to get options:

```js
 static forRootAsync(options: AModuleAsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: AModule,
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      providers: [
         {
            provide: 'something',
            useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
               return config.get('somekey');
            },
            inject: [ConfigService] 
         }
      ],
    };
  }
```

But I need the same to build the `imports` list of child/dependent modules and their options. So the question is if there is a best practices or any other way of doing it.

Comment: Does the `AModule` need the `ConfigModule` or is it only for getting which dynamic children modules there will be?

Comment: No, ConfigModule directly is not required. As you said, it's only for options and getting which children modules needed. An example of when it can happen is implementation of different strategies as child modules and picking one in parent module config.

Comment: I have a similar question to @JayMcDoniel, are you saying that `A1Module` or `A2Module` might need the `ConfigModule` as a dependency? Or are you just saying that another module that imports `AModule` will need the config module as well?